# How to load a comment form in DetailView?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, mixins, django-class-based-views

I was able to load the comments that were added through the admin page but I am not able to make a form in the DetailView itself

I have tried adding a form in the detailview template but I still don't see the form in the site

```
#views.py
class MessageDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Message
    template_name = "messaging/detail.html"
    #queryset = Message.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter(message=self.object)
        return context
```

```
#detail.html
<form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <h3>Write a New Comment</h3>
                <div class="messagebox">
                        {{ form|crispy }}
                        <button class="btn" type="submit">
                            Post Comment
                        </button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

```
#forms.py
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ("comment")
```

```
#models.py
class Comment(models.Model):
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Comment on {}".format(str(self.date_posted))
```

The comments loaded in the site, but the form didn't load, any way to solve this problem? Please provide some code in the answer instead of just linking me to a documentary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you didn't pass the form to your template:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter(message=self.object)
        context['form'] = CommentForm()
        return context
```